# Operador Ternário C#

Tags: c#

Gostaria de adicionar mais uma condição no meu operador ternário. É possível mais de duas condições? Ou existe outra possibilidade?

Preciso inserir a propriedade ProdutoCatalogoDigital que é do tipo BasicoLongDTO.

Atualmente está desta forma:

```
public BasicoLongDTO Produto => ProdutoLivro != null ? new BasicoLongDTO(ProdutoSolucao.Codigo, ProdutoSolucao.Nome) : new BasicoLongDTO(ProdutoBibliotecaDigital.Codigo, ProdutoBibliotecaDigital.Nome);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode sim, utilizo dessa forma:

`([expressão] ? [valor1] : ([expressão] ? [valor1] : ([expressão] ? [valor1] : [valor2])))`

Comment: Deu muito certo! Ficou desta forma: ProdutoLivro != null ? new BasicoLongDTO(ProdutoLivro.Codigo, ProdutoLivro.Nome) :
ProdutoSolucao != null ? new BasicoLongDTO(ProdutoSolucao.Codigo, ProdutoSolucao.Nome) :
ProdutoBibliotecaDigital != null ? new BasicoLongDTO(ProdutoBibliotecaDigital.Codigo, ProdutoBibliotecaDigital.Nome) :
new BasicoLongDTO(ProdutoCatalogoDigital.Codigo, ProdutoCatalogoDigital.Nome);

Answer (score 4):

Sim, é possível.

```
var ternaryResult = (false ? "First Result" : false ? "Second Result" : "Last Result");
```

Veja funcionando no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uGbfMj).

Para mais informações do funcionamento do operador `?:`, [clique aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).